# Multi-texturing using QOpenGLTexture and QOpenGLFrameBufferObject

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, qtopengl

I’m trying to port a previous project to the new Qt5 OpenGL classes. I want to render to a texture using an FBO. The previous code utilized multiple textures which I attaching to the FBO on-demand. So, I would attach a certain texture object, perform the rendering, attach another texture and perform a different operation and have the output rendered to the newly attached texture, and so on.

I was wondering how would I go about doing this using the Qt5 OpenGL classes. For example, I can’t figure out how to attach a certain `QOpenGLTexture` object to a `QOpenGLFrameBufferObject` so that I can render to it. I can see that there is a `texture()` method and a `takeTexture()` method. But they both just return the texture id. Also, how can I change the active texture unit? For example, I want to sample from two textures in my shader program. So, I need to bind two textures to different texture units.

To clarify, the main problem I'm having with the new API is that I don’t see any method in `QOpenGLFrameBufferObject` that would return a `QOpenGLTexture` object. There is only the `toImage()` method and the `texture()` and `takeTexture()` methods. I guess I could just construct a `QOpenGLTexture` using the `QImage` returned from `toImage()`. But I’m not sure if that would be efficient.

As for `texture()` and `takeTexture()`, I don’t see how their return values can be used using the new classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, QOpenGLFrameBufferObject predates QOpenGLTexture and as such, it doesn't use or expose QOpenGLTexture. It should be added, but actually, QOpenGLFBO should be just rewritten to support multiple attachments.

Apart from this, what's the problem at manually using GL calls?

```
GLuint textureId = fbo->texture();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE9);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, anotherTexture);

QOpenGLTexture *yetAnother = getTexture();
yetAnother->bind(2);

program->setUniformValue("samplerForTheFBOTexture", GL_TEXTURE4 - GL_TEXTURE0);
program->setUniformValue("my3dSampler", GL_TEXTURE9 - GL_TEXTURE0);
program->setUniformValue("anotherSampler", 2);
// or use layout (binding = ) in GLSL
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for the example. I thought there was a way to do this cleanly using only the Qt5 OpenGL wrapper classes without mixing them with manual GL calls. Apparently that is the only way to do it for now and Qt's classes are still missing some features.

Comment: I'm preparing a new FBO class (exposing QOpenGLTexture) but that will be Qt 5.5 material...

Comment: That would be great. Looking forward to see that in future versions. Thanks again, you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I added a feature request to the Qt bugtracker to support multiple render targets (MRT) for the QOpenGLFramebufferObject. It is currently in progress and it seems only the code review is pending.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39235

So stay tuned for change logs of future Qt versions.

Comment: It would be great to have that feature. Thanks for the update!